# Summary Join query taking too long

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I am trying to get the max record of each 'telephone_number' where process_status='0' and for that I am using the below query.

```
SELECT ID, CUSTID, telephone_number, TOTAL_USAGE, ACCOUNT_STATUS
FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA t
JOIN (SELECT MAX( id ) AS maxid FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA GROUP BY telephone_number)dt
ON t.id = dt.maxid WHERE process_status = '0'
AND RESET_FLAG = '0'
ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,700
```

The above query is giving me the desired result but the problem is this is too slow..

My table has about 20 million rows and this query is taking about 15-20 mins at times.

What can be done to improve this?

This is the structure:.

```
CREATE TABLE `SPRINTABLE_DATA` (
 `ID` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `CUSTID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `telephone_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TOTAL_USAGE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PROCESS_STATUS` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `RESET_FLAG` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `RESET_REASON` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PLAN_ID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ACCOUNT_STATUS` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `telephone_number` (`telephone_number`),
 KEY `CALL_CUST` (`CALL_START_TIME`,`CUSTID`),
 KEY `telephone_number1` (`telephone_number `,`PROCESS_STATUS`,`SOC_ADDED`),
 KEY `CURRENT_USAGE` (`CURRENT_USAGE`),
 KEY `TOTAL_USAGE` (`TOTAL_USAGE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36392272 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Table definition would help

Comment: sorry! but i could not provide the whole table definition, but surely i can give few of them on demand..

Comment: I don't have much expertise in DBs, but my first guess would be the group by. Do you have any index in the `telephone_number` field?

Comment: @Mihai is not asking for the table's contents, but for the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE SPRINTABLE_DATA`.

Comment: Why can't you provide the whole table definition?  It's going to be hard to help without knowing what you're doing!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for the 700 most recently called numbers. (If that is not correct, please edit your question.

Your query follows a good practice for retrieving the latest log row for each item (telephone number in your case), as follows, in your subquery.

```
   SELECT MAX( id ) AS id 
    FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA  
GROUP BY telephone_number
```

To optimize the performance of this subquery, you need a compound index on two fields: `(telephone_number, id)`, in that order. If you don't have that index, add it in. This is to allow a so-called loose index scan, an extraordinarily efficient way of satisfying a query.

Secondly, you're looking for (I presume) a small subset of your data.  Presumably you have plenty more than 700 distinct `telephone_number` values. This means you're sorting a lot of data with ORDER BY only to discard it with LIMIT. So, let's do a deferred join, sorting a minimal number of columns, and then retrieving all the information you need.

Here's how to get the ID values of the 700 rows you need

```
SELECT q.ID   /* get our 700 records */
  FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA q
  JOIN (
          SELECT MAX( id ) AS id 
           FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA  
       GROUP BY telephone_number
       ) r ON q.id = r.id
  WHERE q.process_status = '0'
    AND q.RESET_FLAG = '0'
  ORDER BY q.ID DESC
  LIMIT 0,700
```

This pulls out 700 id numbers.  You need to do some experimenting with indexes to find out what helps the most to optimize this.  It's possible that an index on

```
   process_status, RESET_FLAG, id
```

will help. It's also possible that changing the order of columns in the index will help, like this:

```
   id, process_status, RESET_FLAG
```

Try them both.

Finally, we'll use this as a subquery to carry out the join (the so-called deferred join) to fetch the actual detail records. This technique gets rid of the need for sorting all that data.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.CUSTID, t.telephone_number, t.TOTAL_USAGE, t.ACCOUNT_STATUS
  FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA t
  JOIN (
          SELECT q.ID  /* get our 700 records */
            FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA q
            JOIN (
                    SELECT MAX( id ) AS id 
                     FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA  
                 GROUP BY telephone_number
                 ) r ON q.id = r.id
            WHERE q.process_status = '0'
              AND q.RESET_FLAG = '0'
            ORDER BY q.ID DESC
            LIMIT 0,700
       ) s ON t.ID = s.ID
  ORDER BY t.ID DESC
```

This will yield the same results, but will be faster.

Now, finally, if it's possible to select the latest calls from the 700 numbers that meet your criteria, you can simplify this query a lot. This will change your result set in a subtle way, though. In that case your call-selection subquery will look like this:

```
                    SELECT MAX( id ) AS id  /* 700 matching numbers */
                     FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA  
                    WHERE process_status = '0'
                      AND reset_flag = '0'
                 GROUP BY telephone_number
                 ORDER BY ID desc
                    LIMIT 0,700
```

With a compound covering index on

```
   reset_flag, process_status, telephone_number, ID
```

this query will be quite fast.  Your final query in this case would be

```
SELECT t.ID, t.CUSTID, t.telephone_number, t.TOTAL_USAGE, t.ACCOUNT_STATUS
  FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA t
  JOIN (
                    SELECT MAX( id ) AS id  /* 700 matching numbers */
                     FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA  
                    WHERE process_status = '0'
                      AND reset_flag = '0'
                 GROUP BY telephone_number
                 ORDER BY ID desc
                    LIMIT 0,700
       ) s ON t.ID = s.ID
  ORDER BY t.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a slight modification to your query

```
  SELECT ID, CUSTID, telephone_number, TOTAL_USAGE, ACCOUNT_STATUS
    FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA t
    JOIN (SELECT telephone_number,MAX( id ) AS maxid FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA GROUP BY telephone_number)dt
    ON t.id = dt.maxid WHERE process_status = '0'
    AND RESET_FLAG = '0'
    ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,700
```

Add these indexes if are not there already

```
ALTER TABLE SPRINTABLE_DATA  ADD KEY (telephone_number,id)
ALTER TABLE SPRINTABLE_DATA  ADD KEY (process_status,reset_flag,id)
```

Another option which is probably the fastest is to use a correlated subquery

```
  SELECT ID, CUSTID, telephone_number, TOTAL_USAGE, ACCOUNT_STATUS
    FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA t WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT MAX( id )  FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA tt WHERE t.id=tt.id AND tt.process_status = '0'
    AND tt.RESET_FLAG = '0'   )     
    ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,700
```

For this you need

```
ALTER TABLE SPRINTABLE_DATA  ADD KEY (id,process_status,reset_flag)
```

Comment: The first key's columns are in the wrong order to optimize the subquery.

Comment: @OllieJones Are you sure?`SELECT telephone_number,MAX( id ) AS maxid FROM SPRINTABLE_DATA GROUP BY telephone_number` will use the first index. MAX and then GROUP BY

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's grouping by telephone number, then looking for the max id in each group. That's known as a loose index scan.

Comment: @OllieJones & Mihai - So, whats the outcome, shall I proceed with the solution provided above??

Comment: @Tarun Edited,just run those 2 statements.